# AWS DMS S3 to SQL Server Migrations - Specify DATETIME2 as SQL Server data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

I am trying to use AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) to populate a SQL Server 2014 table from S3. I have the following S3 schema:

```
{
  "TableCount": "1",
  "Tables": [
    {
      "TableName": "employee",
      "TablePath": "public/employee/",
      "TableOwner": "",
      "TableColumns": [
        {
          "ColumnName": "Id",
          "ColumnType": "INT8",
          "ColumnNullable": "false",
          "ColumnIsPk": "true"
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "HireDate",
          "ColumnType": "TIMESTAMP"
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "Name",
          "ColumnType": "STRING",
          "ColumnLength": "20"
        }
      ],
      "TableColumnsTotal": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the migration task, I get the below overflow error because SQL Server will not allow the value `2018-04-11 08:02:16.788027` from S3 to be inserted into a SQL Server `DATETIME` column.

My question is, is there a way that I can tell AWS DMS to create `TIMESTAMP` S3 data as `DATETIME2` columns in SQL Server? **Note:** Each time the migration runs, the table is dropped and recreated. I can workaround this by manually creating the table myself in SQL-Server with HireDate as `DATETIME2`, then setting the DMS migration 'target table preparation mode' to `TRUNCATE` rather than drop/create but this is not ideal for my current solution.

```
[TARGET_LOAD ]E: Failed to execute statement: 'INSERT INTO [public].[employee]([Id],[HireDate],[Name]) values (?,?,?)' [1022502] (ar_odbc_stmt.c:2456)
[TARGET_LOAD ]E: RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 22008 NativeError: 0 Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding. Line: 1 Column: 4 [1022502] (ar_odbc_stmt.c:2462)
[TARGET_LOAD ]E: Invalid input for column 'HireDate' of table 'public'.'employee' in line number 1.(sqlserver_endpoint_imp.c:2357)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to specify the `"ColumnScale"` attribute in your S3 schema for `timestamp` columns, this will ensure that the SQL Server target column is created as `DATETIME2(7)` i.e.

```
{
  "TableCount": "1",
  "Tables": [
    {
      "TableName": "employee",
      "TablePath": "public/employee/",
      "TableOwner": "",
      "TableColumns": [
        {
          "ColumnName": "Id",
          "ColumnType": "INT8",
          "ColumnNullable": "false",
          "ColumnIsPk": "true"
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "HireDate",
          "ColumnType": "TIMESTAMP",
          "ColumnScale": "7",
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "Name",
          "ColumnType": "STRING",
          "ColumnLength": "20"
        }
      ],
      "TableColumnsTotal": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```